# Get rid from one column duplicate values in two column select

Tags: sql, oracle, output-formatting

So, I`ve got two columns t1.NAME and t2.ITEMS, for each neme there can be more than one item assigned to it, so I want to select it like:

```
| NAME | ITEMS |
  JOHN    1
          2
  BEN     4
          7
          3
  DAVE    5
```

P.s. if it helps, they are connected by t1.id = t2.names_id

Comment: Is there any field which is common in these two tables?

Comment: Use **BREAK ON column_name** in **SQL*Plus**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of my below query is very close to what you want.. the only difference is, there is no blank name, because you cannot directly do that result in one step query.. each item belong to name of each id in t1. BUT you can do some trick there if you want to get the exact result, you can use `UPDATE` to do some trick with the result.

```
    SELECT t1.NAME, t2.ITEMS
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.names_id
```

Comment: thanks in the end i used above select and then in java just didn't save any results in array from resultSet if name id from previous row mach current row name id :)

Comment: @JohnRazerby Your welcome, and sounds good :) because it seems you got exactly what i mean when i say "trick", you've got it on your own :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation should be done in presentation layer.

[image] 
[image]

But if you insist you can use sth like:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d915/6/0)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME,
      LISTAGG(Items,  chr(13)||chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS Items
FROM tab
```

change tab with subquery that produce output you get now.

The clue is to concatenate for every name corresponding Items and adding new line character `CHR(13) + CHR(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it in **SQL*Plus** and it is all about **formatting your output**.

You could use **BREAK ON *column_name***.

For example,

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL> SELECT deptno, ename FROM emp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
           KING
           MILLER
        20 JONES
           FORD
           ADAMS
           SMITH
           SCOTT
        30 WARD
           TURNER
           ALLEN
           JAMES
           BLAKE
           MARTIN

14 rows selected.
```