# Combine GROUP BY and LIKE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, group-by

My objective is to display states that have 20+ of the value in the 2nd column..
Currently I have been able to display states and the values but I need to combine states that are similar and their values (e.g VIC and Vic and vic should equal VIC 68). 
I also only want to display States, not their values but the values keep showing. I'm guessing its using LIKE combined with GROUP BY but I can't figure out how.

My current SQL query:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.STATE, COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) FROM ACADEMIC
JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTNUM=ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.STATE;
```

Output:

```
STATE COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM)
----- -----------------------
NSW                        82 
                            7 
QLD                        21 
VIC                        14 
vic                         1 
WA                         42 
Tas                         1 
SA                         40 
Qld                        55 
Vic                        53 
ACT                        35 
TAS                         8
```

I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: I think you shoudn't do it in DB. This is presentation matter only. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32882720/5070879

Comment: You need **SUM** and **GROUP BY(UPPER/LOWER)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.STATE, COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) FROM ACADEMIC
JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTNUM=ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.STATE
HAVING COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) >= 20;
```

Use `HAVING` to return only rows where the count is 20+.

To take care of different case, do `UPPER` on all states:

```
SELECT UPPER(DEPARTMENT.STATE), COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) FROM ACADEMIC
JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTNUM=ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM
GROUP BY UPPER(DEPARTMENT.STATE)
HAVING COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) >= 20;
```

Comment: But this also shows the 2nd column which contains the quantity. Is there any way to do this but only show the states?

Comment: Simply remove ", COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) FROM ACADEMIC" from the select-list! (I.e. do SELECT DEPARTMENT.STATE.)

Comment: @james But your requirement is different, you wanted to sum up the counts of similar states. For that you need SUM.

Comment: @james, wait a minute, did just notice the upper/lower problem. Will soon editr.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to combine states that are similar and their values (e.g VIC and Vic and vic should equal VIC 68)

You need to use **SUM** and **GROUP BY(UPPER/LOWER)** on your sub-query or simply use **UPPER/LOWER** in the **GROUP BY** expression in your original query.

For example,

```
SQL> with data as(
  2  select 'VIC' state, 14 cnt from dual union all
  3  select 'vic' state, 1  cnt from dual union all
  4  select 'Vic' state, 53  cnt from dual
  5  )
  6  select upper(state), sum(cnt) count
  7  from data
  8  group by upper(state);

UPP      COUNT
--- ----------
VIC         68
```

Since you already have the sub-query which gives you the count, all you need to use **UPPER/LOWER** in **GROUP BY**, such that the **count would now consider similar states**:

```
SELECT UPPER(DEPARTMENT.STATE) AS "STATE"
FROM ACADEMIC
JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTNUM=ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM
GROUP BY UPPER(DEPARTMENT.STATE)
HAVING COUNT(ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM) >= 20;
```