# SQL server result in a particular pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, resultset

Currently I am getting a query result in below format,

```
**state** **city** 
State1 City1

State1 City2

State1 City3

State2 City4

State2 City5
```

But I need the result in below format,

```
**state** **city** 

State1 City1

       City2

       City3

State2 City4

       City5
```

By using only sql, how to get the result in that particular pattern for N no. of columns, so that common values of the next rows become empty.

Comment: This is task for presentation layer and merging cells. Similiar but for Oracle [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32882720/5070879)

Comment: Yes @lad2025 , but i need the same in SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in following:

```
select case when rn > 1 then '' else [state] end as [State], 
       city 
from(
    select  [state], 
            [city], 
            row_number() over(partition by [state] order by [state]) rn
    from YourTable
) x
```

**OUTPUT**

```
State   city
State1  City1
        City2
        City3
State2  City4
        City5
```

Comment: Thanks stanislovas. We need 3 rows with new line.

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee What do you mean 3 rows with new line?

Comment: it is working. But I will try in the requirement and let u know

Answer (score 1):

I discourage to do this, because it is task for presentation layer, but if you insist you can use below code.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372934)**

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(State NVARCHAR(100), City NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES('State1','City1'),
('State1', 'City2'),
('State1', 'City3'),
('State2', 'City4'),
('State2', 'City5');

SELECT DISTINCT 
   State,
   [City] = REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ',' + t2.City
                   FROM #tab t2
                   WHERE t2.State = t.State
                   ORDER BY t2.City
                   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''), ',', CHAR(10) + CHAR(13))
FROM #TAB t
ORDER BY State;
```

*Warning* 
In demo you don't see new lines because it is not supported here. But with your grid view you should be able to see it in application. New line is `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)`.

[Proof](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372936) that new line character is there.

Comment: results are coming in two rows ( state 1, and State 2)

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee There are new line characters, but you don't see them in demo

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee Are you kidding me? First row is table header.

Comment: I know it's completely presentation layer task, but we need to do same in sql end.

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee So decide do you want 5 rows with empty State name for the same or: you want 2 rows with newline characters between data???

Comment: I have executed and but still I am getting two rows and comma separated value in the city column.

Comment: 5 rows with empty State name for the same ...yes .

Comment: @SagnikMukherjee I end this discussion, you don't understand that SSMS grid view cannot display new line character. Try with application grid view from C# or JAVA.