# Make rownum value null in the same values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the sql code and i want for every unique value from COLUMN1 the same rownum.
For example in the example i want null values for rownum 2,3 and for column 2 rownum 2

```
   select rownum,
   t1.column1 as column1,
   t1.Column2 as column2,
   t3.Column3 as column3
from Table1 t1,Table3 t3,Table2 t2
where t3.S_ID=t2.AS_ID
and t2.KT_ID=t1.T_ID
```

[image]

How can i implement this?

Comment: which rdbms you  r using..??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid from one column duplicate values in two column select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882516/get-rid-from-one-column-duplicate-values-in-two-column-select)

Comment: what you want for 4..two or 4..write expected output as well

Comment: for rownum 4 i want 2,because it refers in different value

Comment: For the first part you can use DENSE_RANK to match Column1 with row number .2nd part of null is not clear..post desired output

Comment: find below a solution but it will give you 1 as rownumber for each different group..

Answer (score 2):

First, learn proper explicit `join` syntax.  Second, you can readily do what you want using `lag()` and other analytic functions:

```
select (case when column1 = lag(column1) over (order by column1, column3)
             then NULL
             else dense_rank() over (order by column1)
        end) as rn,
       t1.column1 as column1,
       t1.Column2 as column2,
       t3.Column3 as column3
from Table1 t1 join
     Table2 t2
     on t2.KT_ID = t1.T_ID join
     Table3 t3
     on t3.S_ID = t2.AS_ID
order by column1, column3;
```

Some notes:

- SQL queries return *unordered* result sets.  If you want rows in a particular order -- or even in the same order the next time you run the query -- then include an `order by`.
- I arbitrarily added `column3` to the ordering.  It can be any column that makes the sort *stable*.  That is, each row has a unique set of order keys, so they are in the same order each time.
- The same ordering conditions are used for the `lag()` functions, but only `column1` is used for the `dense_rank()`.
- Learn explicit `join` syntax.  It is more powerful, and almost everyone thinks it is easier to read.

Comment: +1 for actually bothering to explain what you're doing, plus proper `join` and dispelling the common beginner's assumption that tables reliably have an innate order.

Answer (score 0):

```
        This might help you...

       select rownum,column1,column2,column3 from (

Select rownum,column1,column2,column3,
row_number() over( partition by column1,column2 order by column1,column2) as analytic_rnm
from(
select rownum,
   column1 as column1,
   Column2 as column2,
   Column3 as column3
from  Table1 t1,Table3 t3,Table2 t2
where t3.S_ID=t2.AS_ID
and t2.KT_ID=t1.T_ID 
)X
)M
where analytic_rnm=1

union all
select NULL as rownum,
column1,column2,column3  from (
Select rownum,column1,column2,column3,
row_number() over( partition by column1,column2 order by column1,column2) as analytic_rnm
from(
select rownum,
   column1 as column1,
   Column2 as column2,
   Column3 as column3
from  Table1 t1,Table3 t3,Table2 t2
where t3.S_ID=t2.AS_ID
and t2.KT_ID=t1.T_ID
)X)Y
where analytic_rnm>1
```

Comment: replace test111  with your from...condition

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   case when row_number() -- if it's the first row per group...
             over(partition by column1
                  order by column3) = 1
        then dense_rank() -- ... return 1,2,3
             over(order by column1)
        else null
   end,
   t1.column1 as column1,
   t1.Column2 as column2,
   t3.Column3 as column3
from Table1 t1,Table3 t3,Table2 t2
where t3.S_ID=t2.AS_ID
and t2.KT_ID=t1.T_ID
```